# Docker exec container pytest fail

Tags: docker, pytorch, pytest, rapids

I am using the dev image so i can have the cuda compiler, now the issue is that when running the CI, as below I get that error, but if I build the standard container (commented line in dockerfile).

```
CONTAINER=$(docker run -d gpu-test)
docker exec $CONTAINER pytest
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "pytest": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Pulls the basic Image from NVIDIA repository
FROM rapidsai/rapidsai-dev:22.04-cuda11.5-devel-ubuntu20.04-py3.9
# FROM rapidsai/rapidsai:22.04-cuda11.5-runtime-ubuntu20.04-py3.9

# Updates OS libraries
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    --fix-missing git python3-setuptools python3-pip build-essential libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    zlib1g-dev rsync vim nano cmake tabix

# Install libraries needed in the examples
RUN /opt/conda/envs/rapids/bin/pip install \
     scanpy==1.9.1 wget pytabix dash-daq \
     dash-html-components dash-bootstrap-components dash-core-components \
     utils pytest

RUN /opt/conda/envs/rapids/bin/pip install \
    torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116

WORKDIR /workspace
ENV HOME /workspace
```

Comment: You need to add bash `docker exec $CONTAINER bash -c "pytest"` or `docker exec $CONTAINER bash -c "python -m pytest"

Comment: @Macintosh_89 Thank you very much for you input. would you be so kind to explain why?

Comment: You need shell to execute command hence `bash`